# Will ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool.submit(new class()) cause memory leak?

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, executorservice

I'm trying to use `ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool` to running several tasks. Every time I submit to `ExecutorService`, I will new a `class()` which holds task related information.

Will it cause memory leak as time goes?

For example, will there be 1M classes if I `submit()` 1M times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the executor service will not hold a reference beyond the lifetime of the task.

Comment: So in theory the new'ed class will be gc'ed by jvm?

Comment: Yes, if there are no references to it anywhere else.